# validate form and show the items that were not filled in the alert

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, alert

I'm wanting to validate a form in such a way that all fields that are not filled out appear in the alert like this here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/unH29.png

I can only get them to appear in the following way I fill the first one, and the others not, then only the second input appears in the alert, and not all, in the same way that if I fill the first and the second, only the third input will appear in the alert and not all

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUlOD.png

this is my javascript code

```
function validar() {

    var nome = document.getElementById("nome");
    var cpf = document.getElementById("cpf");
    var data = document.getElementById("data");
    var sexo = document.getElementById("sexo");
    var email = document.getElementById("email");
    var celular = document.getElementById("celular");
    var nivel = document.getElementById("nivel");
    var media = document.getElementById("media").checked;

  
    if (nome.value == "") {
        alert("Nome não informado");

     
        nome.focus();
        
        return;
    }
    if (cpf.value == "") {
        alert("CPF não informado");
        cpf.focus();
        return;
    }
    if (data.value == "") {
        alert("Nascimento não informado");
        data.focus();
        return;
    }
    if (sexo.value == "") {
        alert("Sexo não informada");
        sexo.focus();
        return;
    }
    if (email.value == "") {
        alert("Email não informado");
        email.focus();
        return;
    }
    if (celular.value == "") {
        alert("Celular não informado");
        celular.focus();
        return;
    }
    if (nivel.value == "") {
        alert("Nivel não informado");
        nivel.focus();
        return;
    }
    if (media.value == "") {
        alert("Media não informado");
        media.focus();
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have different types of input, I think you can use a simple solution like following:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const t1 = document.getElementById("t1");
  const t2 = document.getElementById("t2");
  const t3 = document.getElementById("t3");
  
  let msg="";  
        
  if(!t1.value) { // or checked
    msg += "t1 is null \n";
  }
  
  if(!t2.value){
    msg += "t2 is null \n";
  }
  
  if(!t3.value){
    msg += "t3 is null \n";
  }
    
  alert(msg);
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<input type="text" id="t1" />
<br>
<input type="text" id="t2" />
<br>
<input type="text" id="t3" />


<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let's clean up the code a bit.
Since you're using the same format for every validation, it does not exactly make sense to reuse to create ten if statements.

In addition, we could filter all of the elements who are lacking a value (AKA Falsey), and have them mapped out based on their inner text (Obviously you should modify this otherwise if the inner text is not equal to the name)

```js
const elements = [nome, cpf, data, sexo, email, celular, nivel, media]
const filtered = elements.filter(element => !element.value)
if (filtered.length > 0) {
  filtered.forEach(element => element.focus())
  return alert(filtered.map(element => element.innerText).join('\n'))
}
```